# Gatsby not watching sanity for new published changes

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, gatsby, netlify, sanity

I have a Gatsby site deployed to netlify. In development mode I set the option `watchMode:true` of gatsby-source-sanity `in gatsby-config.js` and this works fine to watch sanity studio for changes but in production it does not. I have tried adding a token and toggling the `watchMode` between `true` and `false`. The only way I see changes in production is to re build my site on Netlify

Comment: Is the question not clear because it's getting down voted? I dont mind the down votes tho but a clarification would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`watchMode` is only relevant when developing. Netlify hosts a static build from Gatsby, so the only way to get new Sanity content in production it to rebuild *(or fetch content on the client, but probably not what you want in this case)*.

You can create a webhook that will fire when content is updated in Sanity that can trigger a new build in Netlify. [Example from Sanity docs](https://www.sanity.io/blog/how-to-quickly-set-up-a-gatsby-js-jamstack-website-with-a-headless-cms#trigger-new-netlify-builds-on-content-changes-52f5edfa3342).

Comment: Thanks a lot, solves my problem. Gatsby build cache plugin is also great to optimize each build. Incase you want to use less build minute.